# How to display message after registration in the same modal?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

This is my code for HTML form. When I click on register, it takes me to another page. But, I want the message to display on the same modal form.

```
<div class="popup">
                <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                <p>Please enter your details here</p>
                <form action="script.php" method="post" class="registration_form" id="postForm">
                <div id="flash_success">
                    <label for="email">Login (Email)</label>
                    <input type="text" id="e-mail" name="e-mail" value="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" value="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="name">name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="College">College</label>
                    <input type="text" id="College" name="College" value="" />
                </div>
```

I used an Ajax Script to do the same, but couldn't get the desired result.

>

```
 <script>   
    var options = { 
>         target:        '#flash_success',  // your response show in this ID
>       //  beforeSubmit:  callValidationFunction,
>         success:       YourResponseFunction  
>     };
>     // bind to the form's submit event
>         jQuery('#postForm').submit(function() { 
>             jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
>             return false; 
>         }); 
> 
> 
> }); function callValidationFunction() {  //  validation code for your
> form HERE }
> 
> function YourResponseFunction(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
>     if(responseText=='success')
>     {
>         $('#flash_success').html('Your Success Message Here!!!');
>         $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
> 
>     }else
>     {
>         $('#flash_success').html('Error Msg Here');
> 
>     } } </script>
```

And my PHP script is this:

```
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
  $error = array();//Declare An Array to store any error message  
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a name ';//add to array "error"
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];//else assign it a variable
    }

    if (empty($_POST['e-mail'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
    } else {


        if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['e-mail'])) {
           //regular expression for email validation
            $Email = $_POST['e-mail'];
        } else {
             $error[] = 'Your EMail Address is invalid  ';
        }


    }


    if (empty($_POST['Password'])) {

        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
    } else {
         if (preg_match("/^([0-9])+$/", $_POST['Password'])) {
            $Password = $_POST['Password'];
        } else {
             $error[] = 'Please enter a valid phone number  ';
        //$Password = $_POST['Password'];
    }
    if (empty($_POST['College'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your College ';
    } else {
        $College = $_POST['College'];
    }

}

    if (empty($error)) //send to Database if there's no error '

    { // If everything's OK...

        // Make sure the email address is available:
        $query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM members  WHERE Email ='$Email'";
        $result_verify_email = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_verify_email);
        if (!$result_verify_email) {            echo ' Database Error Occured ';
        }

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_email) == 0) { // IF no previous user is using this email .


            // Create a unique  activation code:
            $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));


            $query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO `members` ( `Username`, `Email`, `Password`, `College`, `Activation`) VALUES ( '$name', '$Email', '$Password', '$College' '$activation')";


            $result_insert_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_insert_user);
            if (!$result_insert_user) {
                echo 'Query Failed ';
            }

            if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { //If the Insert Query was successfull.


                // Send the email:
                $message = " To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
                $message .= WEBSITE_URL . '/activate.php?email=' . urlencode($Email) . "&key=$activation";
                mail($Email, 'Registration Confirmation', $message, 'From: creative.virus23@gmail.com');

                // Flush the buffered output.


                // Finish the page:
                echo '<div class="success">Thank you for
registering! A confirmation email
has been sent to '.$Email.' Please click on the Activation Link to Activate your account </div>';


            } else { // If it did not run OK.
                echo '<div class="errormsgbox">You could not be registered due to a system
error. We apologize for any
inconvenience.</div>';
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an iframe, set the form target to the submitter, the action to the script file

```
<iframe name="submitter" id="submitter"></iframe>

<form action="script.php" target="submitter" method="post" class="registration_form" id="postForm">
</form>
```

And finally in your "script.php" include jquery + this code.

```
<script>
parent.$('#postForm').html('Successfully submitted.');
</script>
```

BTW: Didn´t read your full script...but i think this is what you want...

Comment: I don´t know..where is it stored? below your form? Where is it called? where is your form submit button? Your script isn´t complete and I´m tired... Just thought this might help you ;) and this solves the problem you postet.

Comment: Yes, it's below the form in the HTML page.